# Not able use same component for different routes in angular

Tags: angular, routes

I have following routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
  {path: "", HomeComponent},
  {path: ":id", HomeComponent}
]
```

I am not able access the second route

```
localhost:4200/123   => error
```

Error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '/123'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '/123'

Comment: Seem working stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-hdmpkh

Comment: thanks it's working i didn't save the code so, it was giving error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, please clear the cache and re run!

```
{ path: ':id', component: HomeComponent }
```

:)

Comment: i am getting below error
Uncaught Error: Invalid configuration of route '/:id': path cannot start with a slash